# How can I return null in Java when the method is defined as int data type?

Tags: java, types, null, integer, return

I've been doing a code where its mandatory to use the data type cannot be void and I don't need to return anything.

Comment: *How can I return null in Java when the method is defined as int*: you can't

Comment: as @fantaghirocco said, you can not return null if the method type is `int`. but if the method is dealing with arrays or lists, and the location of elements in the array or the list, you can return `-1` to indicate that the element is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, `null` is only a valid value for reference types. It cannot represent a primitive type such as `int`. Here are some alternatives to consider:

1. If you are using Java 8 or later, and are able to change the return type of the method you could use the [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) type  to represent an `int` value that may or may not be present. In that case, you would return `OptionalInt.empty()` in the case that there is no `int` value to return, and `OptionalInt.of(x)` to return an `int x`. Note  that the caller will need to unwrap the `int` value (if it is present) using one of the other methods available on that class. This approach is often preferred for new code, as it makes the intention and usage very clear.
2. If you are using an older Java version, another possibility is to change the return type to [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). This is a wrapper class for `int` values that does allow for `null` to be returned. In addition, Java's [auto-unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) rules allow it to be used in contexts where an `int` value is expected, when the value is not `null`. However, if a `null` value is unboxed to an `int` value, it will result in a `NullPointerException`, so it is important to  check for `null` before performing operations that would result in unboxing.
3. If you need to use the `int` return type, it is common to use a *sentinal value* to represent an abnormal return. For example, if the normal return values for the method are all non-negative integers, you could use a value such as `-1` to represent an absent return value. This is commonly used in older JDK methods such as [`String.indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).
4. In some cases, it makes sense to throw an `Exception` when no valid value can be returned. It's only a good idea to use this approach for truly exceptional circumstances, as the runtime cost for throwing exceptions is much higher than normal method returns, and the flow of control can make the code harder to understand.